# Perl script debugging through the command line gives error

Tags: perl, shell

While I am executing my perl script, I am getting following error: `Can't locate Text/Unidecode.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Text::Unidecode module)`

Comment: Have you installed the Text::Unidecode module?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to make it brief and concise.
I also edited your question to make it more understandable and readable. 
Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more information on formatting. Please edit in the specific error -message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: @S1LENTWARRIOR Actually a concise title would be _“What to do when Perl cannot find the Text::Unidecode module?”_ (And the answer would be _“Install it, with e.g. `sudo cpan Text::Unidecode`”._)

Comment: @PerlDog no, just `cpan Text::Unidecode` with CPAN configured to use sudo for installing (but importantly *not* for building/testing)

Comment: @ysth Ahh, thank you. I'll read on that further, because I did it wrong all the time before. I always used `cpan` like I used `apt-get install`: with `sudo`.